# Vapor 3 API: embed Future<Model> in response object

Tags: swift, vapor

Suppose I have a model called `Estimate`. I have a Vapor 3 API that I want to return a list of these models, filtered by query parameters. Doing so currently returns a `Future<[Estimate]>`, which results in the API returning JSON that looks like this:

```
[{estimate object}, {estimate object}, ...]
```

Instead, I'd like make it return something this:

```
{"estimates": [{estimate object}, {estimate object}, ...]}
```

So, the same thing as before, but wrapped in a JSON object with a single key, `"estimates"`.

[According to the documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/#dynamic-properties), any time I want to return something non-default, I should make a new type for it; this suggests to me I should create a type like:

```
final class EstimatesResponse: Codable {
  var estimates: [Estimate]?
}
```

However, after filtering I get a `Future<[Estimate]>` and NOT a pure `[Estimate]` array, meaning that I couldn't assign it to my `EstimatesResponse` `estimates` property. It seems weird to make the type of `estimates` be `Future<[Estimate]>`, and I'm not sure how that'd turn out.

How, then, can I return JSON of the correct format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to create Codable object, I prefer struct as below. Must implement protocol **Content** for routing.

```
struct EstimatesResponse: Codable {
  var estimates: [Estimate]
 }

 extension EstimatesResponse: Content { }
```

I assumed that you are using a controller and inside the controller, you can use the following pseudo-code. Adjust your code so that **val** is **Future<[Estimate]>**, then use **flatmap/map** to get **[Estimate]**.

```
func  getEstimates(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<EstimatesResponse> {
        let val = Estimate.query(on: req).all()
        return val.flatMap { model in
            let all = EstimatesResponse(estimates: model)
            return Future.map(on: req) {return all }
        }
    }
```